# Ajax call with JSONP failing on Safari

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, safari, jsonp

I'm making an ajax request to an API that has a different domain name than my site. To make the data accessible across browsers, I am using JSONP, but Safari still blocks it. It works on Chrome however.

I am injecting the response string into an HTML button's text. Am I doing this wrong with JSONP? Do I HAVE to inject JSONP into a script tag for this to work?

Do I have to build a proxy? What are my options client-side? Is there something else that needs to be done on the API server-side?

I have searched SO, but I haven't found any clear answers. I read that actually loading the data into the website in a script tag can be prone to security issues.

Error:

```
different-domain-api.com&callback=jQuery123456&_=56789000
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “different-domain-api.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

// starting module code:

```
var myObject = {},
subscribeBtn = $("#subscribe-btn > span");

myObject.priceChangeHandler = function () {
    priceChangeModule.ajaxRequest(params)
    .done( self.successFunc ) // extracting the success callback to another method
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log("Errors in safari", error);
        return error;
    });
});

myObject.successFunc = function (data) {
    subscribeBtn.text(data.result[0]);
    console.log("Displays data in Chrome correctly", data);
};
```

// priceChangeModule code:

```
ajaxRequest: function (params) {
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: '//different-domain-api.com',
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 120000
    });
}
```

Response:

```
/**/jQuery123456({data});
```

Headers:

```
General:
    Request URL: //different-domain-api.com&callback=jQuery123456&_=56789000

Request Headers:
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Host:different-domain-api.com

Response Headers:
    Content-Type:application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What's the error you get in Safari? *"Do I HAVE to inject JSONP into a script tag for this to work?"* JSONP is nothing by adding a `<script>`. jQuery does this for you automatically (no Ajax request is performed actually).

Comment: @FelixKling sorry I forgot to include the error. Edited the post.

"different-domain-api.com&callback=jQuery123456&_=56789000
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “different-domain-api.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. "

Comment: So, it seems that that `different-domain-api.com` uses an invalid SSL certificate. That has nothing to do with the same-origin policy. I'd look at the certificate to check what is wrong about it.

Comment: This is exactly the same as when you try to go to a website in the browser and it pops up a security warning about an invalid certificate.

Comment: @felix do you know where we look or can access this certificate? thanks

When I paste the url from the console error (https://different-domain-api.com&callback=jQuery123456&_=56789000) in the browser, Safari brings shows a popup with the error message from before and asks if we want to continue.

Comment: The popup might contain a button similar to "Show cerificate"? If not, Safari should show some kind of lock in the address bar. Clicking on this brings up a popup with that button.